# Android Studio 3.0 Update - sun.security.ssl

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

I just updated to Android Studio 3.0 on my Mac (think it said 2.3 before). When opening my project again after installatio I get Gradle sync fail:

Error:Could not initialize class sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$TLSContext

What can I do? Don't recognize or know what the above is. Never saw it before in the older version.

Comment: Way to less data to help you out, post code or build.gradle

Comment: same here someone help

Comment: Are you using JDK 9? I am seeing this error across the board using Java 9 with code that works perfectly in Java 8.